# how to add variations to different phone sizes with the same size class

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-autolayout, xcode11, size-classes

I have researched this issue but it only shows if you have different size classes.

I am trying to finish up my app with auto layouts.  I am only using Portrait mode and only on iPhones so the size class for all the phone sizes is the same `wC hR`.

If from iPhone 11 Pro Max to the iPhone 8 Plus are fine but i need to make adjustments on the iPhone 8, SE and 4s, how do i make a variation if the size classes are the same?  Once i select 'Vary for Traits' and select 'width and height' and make my changes, it now changes the bigger size phones to what i wanted for the smaller size phones.

How can i keep the changes for the bigger size phones and make changes for the smaller size phones so they all fit accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using only portrait mode on only iphone devices you don't need to use Size classes or vary trait. what you need only constraints with multiplier. 
[image]

This will work for all devices from iphone 11 pro max to iphone se.

Comment: Great news! Wish me Luck!